how do i decrypt a cyphertext encrypted with AES with pycryptodome?
I'm making a password manager with python that stores and encrypts passwords (using the pycriptodome module) with a main password set by the user, but the decryption does not work
Here's the function I'm using to decrypt the passwords
def decrypt_data(key, iv, ct):  # Makes the credentials readable and usable
    print(f'{bcolors.warning}\nDebug decrypt_data(1):\tiv:\t\t\t{iv}') # debug text
    print(f'Debug decrypt_data(2):\tiv variable type:\t{type(iv)}') # debug text
    print(f'Debug decrypt_data(3):\tiv_bytes:\t\t{bytes(iv, 'utf-8')}') # debug text
    print(f'Debug decrypt_data(4):\tiv_bytes type:\t\t{type(bytes(iv, 'utf-8'))}\n{bcolors.endc}') # debug text
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
    pt = unpad(cipher.decrypt(bytes(ct, 'utf-8')), AES.block_size)
    print(f'{bcolors.okcyan}Decripting done{bcolors.endc}')
    return decrypted.decode("UTF-8")

Console output:
Debug decrypt_data(1):  iv:                     +00X7cdUZm7L61ifRb9EDQ==
Debug decrypt_data(2):  iv variable type:       <class 'str'>
Debug decrypt_data(3):  iv_bytes:               b'+00X7cdUZm7L61ifRb9EDQ=='
Debug decrypt_data(4):  iv_bytes type:          <class 'bytes'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\py_proj\Password Manager\.venv\Lib\pw_manager.py", line 151, in <module>
    print(f'{bcolors.warning}Debug main(5):\t\tdecrypted main_pw:\t{decrypt_data(padded_key, encrypt_data(padded_key, main_pw)[1], encrypt_data(padded_key, main_pw)[0])}') # debug text
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\py_proj\Password Manager\.venv\Lib\pw_manager.py", line 107, in decrypt_data
    pt = unpad(cipher.decrypt(bytes(ct, 'utf-8')), AES.block_size)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_cbc.py", line 246, in decrypt
    raise ValueError("Data must be padded to %d byte boundary in CBC mode" % self.block_size)
ValueError: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode

Just for reference here's the code for the encryption and part of the main function as well
def encrypt_data(key, pt): # protects the credentials in the file once saved
    print(f'\nDebug encrypt_data(1):\tplaintext:\t\t{pt}') # debug text
    print(f'Debug encrypt_data(2):\tbytetext:\t\t{bytes(pt, 'utf-8')}') # debug text
    print(f'Debug encrypt_data(3):\tpadded plaintext:\t{pad(bytes(pt, 'utf-8'), AES.block_size)}') # debug text
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
    ct_bytes = cipher.encrypt(pad(bytes(pt, 'utf-8'), AES.block_size))
    print(f'Debug encrypt_data(4):\tct_bytes:\t\t{ct_bytes}') # debug text
    iv = b64encode(cipher.iv).decode('utf-8')
    ct = b64encode(ct_bytes).decode('utf-8')
    print(f'Debug encrypt_data(5):\tb64 decoded ct:\t\t{ct}') # debug text
    print(f'Debug encrypt_data(6):\tiv:\t\t\t{iv}') # debug text
    print(f'Debug encrypt_data(7):\tciphertext:\t\t{ct}\n') # debug text
    print(f'Encripting done')

    return ct, iv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # login screen
    if not os.path.exists(credentials_file):
        signin()
    main_pw = login()
    padded_key = pad(bytes(main_pw, 'utf-8'), AES.block_size)  # Pad the key to the correct length
    print(f'Debug main(1):\t\tmain_pw:\t\t{main_pw}') # debug text
    print(f'Debug main(2):\t\tbyte_pw:\t\t{bytes(main_pw, 'utf-8')}') # debug text
    print(f'Debug main(3):\t\tpadded_key:\t\t{padded_key}') # debug text
    print(f'Debug main(4):\t\tencrypted main_pw:\t{encrypt_data(padded_key, main_pw)[0]}') # debug text
    print(f'Debug main(5):\t\tdecrypted main_pw:\t{decrypt_data(padded_key, encrypt_data(padded_key, main_pw)[1], encrypt_data(padded_key, main_pw)[0])}') # debug text
    print(f'Debug main(6):\t\tunpadded decrypted main_pw:\t{decrypt_data(padded_key, encrypt_data(padded_key, main_pw)[1], encrypt_data(padded_key, main_pw)[0])}\n') # debug text

this is the full output of the console:
Debug main(1):          main_pw:                test
Debug main(2):          byte_pw:                b'test'
Debug main(3):          padded_key:             b'test\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c'

Debug encrypt_data(1):  plaintext:              test
Debug encrypt_data(2):  bytetext:               b'test'
Debug encrypt_data(3):  padded plaintext:       b'test\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c'
Debug encrypt_data(4):  ct_bytes:               b'I\xdd\x95\x9fXl"\xa1\xd9Xfd~\xc5\xc2\xcd'
Debug encrypt_data(5):  b64 decoded ct:         Sd2Vn1hsIqHZWGZkfsXCzQ==
Debug encrypt_data(6):  iv:                     lmuFGlygOos07SPYpBWNBw==
Debug encrypt_data(7):  ciphertext:             Sd2Vn1hsIqHZWGZkfsXCzQ==

Encripting done
Debug main(4):          encrypted main_pw:      Sd2Vn1hsIqHZWGZkfsXCzQ==

Debug encrypt_data(1):  plaintext:              test
Debug encrypt_data(2):  bytetext:               b'test'
Debug encrypt_data(3):  padded plaintext:       b'test\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c'
Debug encrypt_data(4):  ct_bytes:               b'\t\r\xfbd\x07\x1d\xcay>\xa49\xdeK\xd9W\xbb'
Debug encrypt_data(5):  b64 decoded ct:         CQ37ZAcdynk+pDneS9lXuw==
Debug encrypt_data(6):  iv:                     +00X7cdUZm7L61ifRb9EDQ==
Debug encrypt_data(7):  ciphertext:             CQ37ZAcdynk+pDneS9lXuw==

Encripting done

Debug encrypt_data(1):  plaintext:              test
Debug encrypt_data(2):  bytetext:               b'test'
Debug encrypt_data(3):  padded plaintext:       b'test\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c'
Debug encrypt_data(4):  ct_bytes:               b'=\xf6\xa4\xcetfD\xe4\x12\xef\xff\xce\x0f(]t'
Debug encrypt_data(5):  b64 decoded ct:         PfakznRmROQS7//ODyhddA==
Debug encrypt_data(6):  iv:                     w/FfW0RCcLqv8FjqRtCpxg==
Debug encrypt_data(7):  ciphertext:             PfakznRmROQS7//ODyhddA==

Encripting done

Debug decrypt_data(1):  iv:                     +00X7cdUZm7L61ifRb9EDQ==
Debug decrypt_data(2):  iv variable type:       <class 'str'>
Debug decrypt_data(3):  iv_bytes:               b'+00X7cdUZm7L61ifRb9EDQ=='
Debug decrypt_data(4):  iv_bytes type:          <class 'bytes'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\py_proj\Password Manager\.venv\Lib\pw_manager.py", line 151, in <module>
    print(f'Debug main(5):\t\tdecrypted main_pw:\t{decrypt_data(padded_key, encrypt_data(padded_key, main_pw)[1], encrypt_data(padded_key, main_pw)[0])}') # debug text
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\py_proj\Password Manager\.venv\Lib\pw_manager.py", line 107, in decrypt_data
    pt = unpad(cipher.decrypt(bytes(ct, 'utf-8')), AES.block_size)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_cbc.py", line 246, in decrypt
    raise ValueError("Data must be padded to %d byte boundary in CBC mode" % self.block_size)
ValueError: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode

[processo terminato con codice 1 (0x00000001)]

I tried padding before decrypting using pt = unpad(cipher.decrypt(pad(bytes(ct, 'utf-8'), AES.block_size)), AES.block_size) instead of pt = unpad(cipher.decrypt(pad(bytes(ct, 'utf-8'), AES.block_size)), AES.block_size) but it gave this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\py_proj\Password Manager\.venv\Lib\pw_manager.py", line 151, in <module>
    print(f'Debug main(5):\t\tdecrypted main_pw:\t{decrypt_data(padded_key, encrypt_data(padded_key, main_pw)[1], encrypt_data(padded_key, main_pw)[0])}') # debug text
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\py_proj\Password Manager\.venv\Lib\pw_manager.py", line 107, in decrypt_data
    pt = unpad(cipher.decrypt(pad(bytes(ct, 'utf-8'), AES.block_size)), AES.block_size)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util\Padding.py", line 92, in unpad
    raise ValueError("Padding is incorrect.")
ValueError: Padding is incorrect.

[processo terminato con codice 1 (0x00000001)]


You probably shouldn't use an unauthenticated cipher mode such as CBC. You do want to be sure that the ciphertext hadn't been tampered with (or corrupted), right?

Secondly: you're returning decrypted.decode(...), but you never assign anything to a decrypted. I don't think the code you're showing us is the code that raises these issues.

Your decrypt_data function doesn't use the IV you pass in as an argument, either.

it's passing the iv argument because in an older version of the program i was creating the cypher object with cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv) but it gave me the error Incorrect IV length (it must be 16 bytes long)'. Removing iv=iv` it didn't output that error anymore but im still not able to check if it decrypts the cyphertexts correctly with or without it because of my main problem, I guess it's a problem for future me. I didn't write about that because i forgot about it.

You must of course use the IV during decryption. The bug in your code is the missing Base64 decoding of ciphertext and IV during decryption. Another bug is that in tests 5 and 6 ciphertext and IV are inconsistent because they come from two different encrypt_data() calls.

Here's a simplified and functioning version of your code that, for simplicity, accepts base64 encoded plain-text strings as key and IV material (these are easy to store in e.g. text files).
Do note that CBC mode is probably not what you want since it doesn't provide any authentication (i.e. that you're getting back the text that was originally encrypted).
import base64
import secrets

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad, pad


def encrypt_data(key_str: str, plaintext: str) -> tuple[str, str]:
    key_bytes = base64.b64decode(key_str.encode("utf-8"))
    cipher = AES.new(key_bytes, AES.MODE_CBC)
    ct_bytes = cipher.encrypt(pad(plaintext.encode("utf-8"), AES.block_size))
    iv = base64.b64encode(cipher.iv).decode("utf-8")
    ciphertext = base64.b64encode(ct_bytes).decode("utf-8")
    return ciphertext, iv


def decrypt_data(key_str: str, iv_str: str, ciphertext_str: str) -> str:
    key_bytes = base64.b64decode(key_str.encode("utf-8"))
    iv_bytes = base64.b64decode(iv_str.encode("utf-8"))
    ciphertext_bytes = base64.b64decode(ciphertext_str.encode("utf-8"))
    cipher = AES.new(key_bytes, AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv_bytes)
    plaintext_bytes = unpad(cipher.decrypt(ciphertext_bytes), AES.block_size)
    return plaintext_bytes.decode("UTF-8")


key_bytes = secrets.token_bytes(32)
key_str = base64.b64encode(key_bytes).decode("utf-8")
plaintext = "Hello, World!"

print(f"{key_str=}, {plaintext=}")
ciphertext, iv = encrypt_data(key_str, plaintext)
print(f"{ciphertext=}, {iv=}")
decrypted = decrypt_data(key_str, iv, ciphertext)
print(f"{decrypted=}")

This prints out (e.g.)
key_str='Zdu1DUQC/dZhGC8Q1n0raD8BlW7pfzLZxwmPqn0o6s8=', plaintext='Hello, World!'
ciphertext='Es7w8eWcRHGhfpwBDnr6vQ==', iv='Grf/VFkH8Qp7VS6RVj2e2g=='
decrypted='Hello, World!'

